# twitter widget loads properly in all themes except my own theme?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, widgets, sidebar

I've written my own theme for my wordpress website. The problem is that the twitter widget loads properly in all the themes except mine. Below is the attachment of the widget in both the themes -

**Twenty Twelve Theme (built-in)**
[image: Twenty Twelve Theme]

and
**My own theme**
[image: My own theme]

Any idea as to why this is happening? I'm using Bootstrap to power my theme if you'd like to know

Comment: have you checked your javascript console?

Comment: @Milo, I'm new to theme development, can you please elaborate?

Comment: your browser has a javascript console that will show errors on the page.

Comment: @Milo, the console window is blank, no errors.
Does it have anything to do with **wp_meta()**?

Comment: not sure what `wp_meta` has to do with it. it would probably help to link the source code of the widget you're using. it's just guessing with the information provided here.